# Xcode runtime error: ".objc_class_name_CContext", referenced from:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, runtime-error

I'm getting this error in Xcode while developing an app for iPhone , what is this error related to, ... what should i do to clear this error?
Here CContext and CManager are interface which implement there own protocols.And TestManagerAppDelegate is the interface where i'm creating the object for CContext and CManager and i want to call the methods using there own objects.

ERROR:

```
".objc_class_name_CContext", referenced from:
".objc_class_name_CManager", referenced from:
collect2:id retirned 1 exit status
literal-pointer@_OBJC@_cls_refs@CContext in TestManagerAppDelegate.o
literal-pointer@_OBJC@_cls_refs@Cmanager in TestManagerAppDelegate.o
symbol(s) not found
```

Comment: Have you forgotten to include a framework?

Comment: no i've included <Foundation/Foundation.h> and <UIKit/UIKit.h>. These are the only 2 frameworks i require in my project

Comment: +1 to Jessedc. I removed the problem from my project following your advice.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the files that contain the implementations for the CContext and CManager classes (probably CContext.m and CManager.m) were not included in your Xcode project.

Comment: @Diederik : i've included both .m files in my project.. i don't knw why this error is popping up..

Comment: Are the class files also assigned to the right target? Could it be that you are running some unit tests from a separate target?